# Execution fails when i try to build my project

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.sharu.places"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}


dependencies {

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:8.4.0'

compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

}
```

Please help me with this problem.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This happens quite frequently.

Just "Clean the project" -> "Rebuild the project", and you will be good to go.